# How to connect to local running server in springboot testing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-rest

My application is running in local with port 8089, I am trying to do Spring Rest Controller testing.

It is running in 8089 port.

In application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: sit
```

In application-sit.yml

```
server:
  port: 8089
  servlet:
    context-path: /myapp
```

In My base test case:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
//@SpringBootTest( webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
//@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("sit")
public abstract class FullOtpControllerTest {
    protected MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Value("${server.port}")
    int serverPort;

    @Test
    public void sendOtpTest() throws Exception {
        String uri = "/sendOtp";
        //{"clientId": "default2","tag": "tag","mobileNumber": "9999988888"}
        SendOTPRequestDTO otpRequest = new SendOTPRequestDTO();
        otpRequest.setClientId("default2");
        otpRequest.setTag("tag");
        otpRequest.setMobileNumber("9321901416");

        String inputJson = mapToJson(otpRequest);
        MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(uri)
                //.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)).andReturn()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .content(inputJson)).andReturn();

        int status = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
        String content = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertEquals(8089,serverPort);
        assertEquals(200, status);

    }
}
```

But , first assert is passed. but in the debug it showing different port as showing in the below image.

[image]

I run: **OtpControllerTest.sendOtpTest** and I am getting:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :200
Actual   :404
```

Comment: You cannot use MockMvc to connect to the real server. That is what `TestRestTemplate` and `TestWebClient` are for.

Comment: Kindly help me with more details please.

Comment: This article on [@SpringBootTest](https://rieckpil.de/guide-to-springboottest-for-spring-boot-integration-tests/) might help. With `MockMvc` you test against the mocked servlet environment (usually done within `@WebMvcTest`). With your test, you need real HTTP communication as you start your embedded servlet container on a local port. In short, remove `MockMvc` and inject the auto-configured `TestRestTemplate` to access your local application.

Answer (score 0):

MockMVC is intended for a different kind of testing.
It works in conjunction with `@WebMvcTest` annotation and allows testing your controller definitions: annotations, parameters, etc.
In this case spring starts a "splice" of the application that is relevant to the  WEB layer, for example, it won't load beans annotated with `@Service` or `@Repository`, but will load all the `@RestController` annotated classes. If the controller depends on some service, you can mock it with a `@MockBean` annotation

In any case it doesn't require any kind of remote application everything runs "in-place".

`@SpringBootTest` annotation serves a different purpose, so you shouldn't run tests annotated with this annotation and use MockMVC instead:
`@SpringBootTest` runs the whole microservice (loads all the beans). Alternatively, there is a "mode" where spring boot test loads only explicitly defined Context Configurations...

If your purpose is black-box testing of the APIs of a remote application - you don't have to use spring at all - you don't need beans, don't need injection - you only need an Http Client of some sort (doesn't even have to be in Java) to implement this kind of tests.

One framework (out of many) is [Rest Assured](https://rest-assured.io/) but again there are many choices here.